# How to open File Chooser Dialog in HTML page by javascript without user interaction

Tags: javascript, html, browser, webview

I have found some examples that trigger "`click`" event to hidden `<input type="file" />` to open a File Chooser dialog by using Javascript.

For example, when a user clicks an image button, the browser shows a File Chooser dialog even if the user does not click [`Browse`] or [`Choose file..`] button which is basically accompanying with `<input type="file" />`.

However, it requires '*user interaction*' that means users have to somehow manually 'click' buttons to open the dialog.

I want to invoke a function to open the dialog without user interaction. However, using 'normal' methods are failed and shows *"File chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation"*

The reason why I need this is that I want to open the dialog in a WebView control in both Android(WebView) and iOS(WKWebView) applications by using Javascript eval()-like method.
But as written above, eval() failed because it is considered non-user interaction. I need an alternative or detour solution.